# Making function for eager loading in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

I have three levels of Category assigned to add product `Primary`, `Secondary`, and `Final` categories. While adding product the user can save the final category id in the category_id field. Now I want to access the product of final categories related to the `Primary` Category.

Let's suppose I have **Electronic** Primary category and under that, I have secondary categories like **Mobiles**, **Camera**, **Desktop** and again inside the `Secondary` categories I have `Final` category like **Samsung**, **Galaxy** inside Mobile, **Canon**, **DSLR** inside the camera and so on. Now I want to be able to fetch all the products inside `Primary` Category.

I have the following code for eager loading:

```
$electronic_accessories = "Electronic Device";
  
$electronic_accessories_product = Product::whereHas('productCategory', function($query) 
          use($electronic_accessories) {
              $query->whereHas('secondaryCategory', function($query) 
              use($electronic_accessories)  { 
                  $query->whereHas('primaryCategory', function($query) 
                  use($electronic_accessories){
                      $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
                  });
              });
        })
        ->with([
          'productCategory' => function($query) use($electronic_accessories) {
              $query->whereHas('secondaryCategory', function($query) use($electronic_accessories)
                { 
                  $query->whereHas('primaryCategory', function($query) 
                    use($electronic_accessories){
                        $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
                    });
                });
          },
          'productCategory.secondaryCategory'=> function($query) use($electronic_accessories)
          {
                  $query->whereHas('primaryCategory', function($query) 
                    use($electronic_accessories){
                        $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
                    });
          },
          'productCategory.secondaryCategory.primaryCategory' =>                   
            function($query) use($electronic_accessories) {
                  $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
          }])->take(2)->get();
```

This code is working perfectly but I don't want to repeat this code on every time I want to get products from `Primary` categories. I want to use this as a function. I tried making function with `getPrimaryProduct()` in `Product` model but it says

> Call to a member function getPrimaryProduct() on null

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a scope :

```
public function scopePrimary($query){
   return $query->whereHas('productCategory', function($query) 
          use($electronic_accessories) {
              $query->whereHas('secondaryCategory', function($query) 
              use($electronic_accessories)  { 
                  $query->whereHas('primaryCategory', function($query) 
                  use($electronic_accessories){
                      $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
                  });
              });
        })
        ->with([
          'productCategory' => function($query) use($electronic_accessories) {
              $query->whereHas('secondaryCategory', function($query) use($electronic_accessories)
                { 
                  $query->whereHas('primaryCategory', function($query) 
                    use($electronic_accessories){
                        $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
                    });
                });
          },
          'productCategory.secondaryCategory'=> function($query) use($electronic_accessories)
          {
                  $query->whereHas('primaryCategory', function($query) 
                    use($electronic_accessories){
                        $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
                    });
          },
          'productCategory.secondaryCategory.primaryCategory' =>                   
            function($query) use($electronic_accessories) {
                  $query->where('name', $electronic_accessories);
          }]);
}
```

then use it :

```
Product::primary()->get();
```